# MySQL join same table twice on different columns without a clash

Tags: php, mysql

This is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM property_table AS property

INNER JOIN property_classification AS classifications
        ON property.classification_id = classifications.id

INNER JOIN property_classification AS classonrequest
        ON property.classonrequest_id = classonrequest.id

WHERE property.id=5000 LIMIT 1;
```

Notice that I'm using the same table `property_classification` on two fields `property.classification_id` and `property.classonrequest_id`.

The structure of `property_classification` is something like:

```
id | a1 | a2 | a3 | ... | d1 | d2
```

When I execute the query above in MySQL Query Browser, I get something like this:

```
id | other 'property' fields | id | a1 | a2 | a3 | ... | id | a1 | a2 | a3 | ...
```

But in my PHP script I am returning associated arrays, and all duplicate field names are overwritten.

What I want is the query to return the two joined tables under the name of their table i.e.:

```
classifications.id | classifications.a1 | classifications.a2 | classifications.a3
```

and

```
classonrequest.id | classonrequest.a1 | classonrequest.a2 | classonrequest.a3
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You specifically rename them instead of using "*" but you're not even selecting any columns from the joined tables. You're only selecting everything from the `property_table`.

Comment: Aliases for all that?you might as well write a novel.

Comment: @DevlshOne I tried `SELECT property.*, classifications.a1, classonrequest.a1 INNER JOIN...` and I got `id | ... | a1 | a1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use table aliases and rename the columns:

```
SELECT classifications.id as cid,
       classifications.a1 as c_a1,
       . . .
       classificaitions.d2 as c_d2
       classonrequest.a1 as cr_a1,
       . . .
FROM property_table AS property
INNER JOIN property_classification AS classifications
        ON property.classification_id = classifications.id
INNER JOIN property_classification AS classonrequest
        ON property.classonrequest_id = classonrequest.id
WHERE property.id=5000
LIMIT 1;
```

To make your job easier, you can run a query like:

```
select concat('c_', column_name, ', ')
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'classification';
```

This will list all the column names for the first group (and you can repeat for the second group using a different prefix.

Comment: Thanks... Is there anyway I can keep them structured like classifications.a1 instead of the prefixing? I guess it's not that important anyway.

Comment: @Ozzy . . . You won't be able to refer to them, because you would have to columns with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT property.*, classifications.*, classonrequest.* FROM property_table AS property

INNER JOIN property_classification AS classifications
        ON property.classification_id = classifications.id

INNER JOIN property_classification AS classonrequest
        ON property.classonrequest_id = classonrequest.id

WHERE property.id=5000 LIMIT 1;
```

But you still won't get the specific table names.

Comment: This is the same as `SELECT *` in my case.